# IIS not recognizing binding to .academy domain

Tags: iis, iis-8

*This will be my first post to serverfault and not stackoverflow.*

#### Problem

I am running af new ASP web application for a new project which I am to host on my windows server along with a dozen other already active (and functioning) applications.

The new project requires an unusual domain *.academy* which has proven to give me issues. I have already succesfully mapped the running application to one of my other domains, but when attempting to bind to the *.academy* domain, hits to the adress fall through to the standard IIS landing page.

**- Note request do actually hit my server**

My experience is mainly within code, and not within server configuration so the solution to this might be triviel. However, this has proven to have wasted many working hours already. Any thoughts?

*Best regards*

Comment: I tested this with a new entry to my hosts file: `foo.academy` and a new binding `*:80:foo.academy` and it works fine (at least in IIS 8.5). Can you post your bindings?

Comment: The problem was that the DNS record was set to the type 'Forward' where it should have been set to 'A'.